How does the "bypass" on a PRV work. & do I need a check valve?
My municipal supply comes in on a 2" line at 160-200 psi (meter installed on my residential sprinkler system) so I have a PRV (which I think at >20 yrs old needs replacing but that is another issue) for the household. I recently installed a hybrid water heater and want to protect it. Local code also required an expansion tank to be added. Research on the existing PRV documents it has a bypass feature which as I understand things, negated the need for the expansion tank for the previous configuration. It seems most new PRVs also have this bypass feature. So, I have 2 questions:

Do I need to install a check valve with the expansion tank and a PRV with bypass? It seems like there is little benefit to installing the expansion tank if the bypass feature on the PRV manages the thermal expansion.
If the supply side is sitting at 200 psi and my system experiences thermal expansion, wouldn't the household pressure have to exceed 200 psi for the water to expand back into the supply?

